# Swift onDelete on nested Arrays

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct FirstView: View {

    @State var idArray: Array<String> = ["a", "b", "c"]

    var body: some View {
         SecondView(idArray: $idArray)
    }
}
```

```
struct SecondView: View {

    @Binding var idArray:Array<String>

    var body: some View {
        List(){
            Section{
                ForEach(0..<self. idArray.count, id: \.self){id in
                    Text(self.idArray[id])
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
            }
        }
    }

    func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
         self.idArray.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

The problem: 
When performing a delete it does not delete the right element but rather the last one.

I think that the `@Binding` is the issue here as before I did not have the List as an own component and everything in one struct and it worked. The own component would help reduce code redundancy in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List {
    Section{
        ForEach(self.idArray, id: \.self){ id in
            Text(id)
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Displaying the values is not an issue. It displays them and everything. Issue is deleting the right one.

Comment: I tested the code above and each item was deleted correctly.

Comment: How would one proceed when you your array doesn't not contain Strings. As in the example code I provided in this question I used an String array for easier understanding but in my code I do have an Array that contains other Struct Views. These have @State values and are therefore not hashable which is required for ForEach to be used like this.